# How to show Day as well as Time in between the days? Multiple data on x-axis Highachrts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph, highcharts

I have multiple data coming on each day and I was wondering how to make a graph where I see the days and when I zoom in I should see the time in between the days. I am not able to do so resulting in a graph with days getting duplicated or triplicated as per the number of data points.

Before Zooming:-
[image]

After Zoom :-
[image]

I would like not to have duplicate Day names rather time in between them.
My Highcharts-ng configuration json object is as follows:-

```
{
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                    zoomType: 'xy',
                    animation: true
                },
                colors:['#2C91DE','#165A8E'],
                plotOptions: {
                    line:{
                        marker:{
                            symbol:'circle'
                        }
                    },
                    series: {
                        lineWidth: 3, 
                        marker: {
                            fillColor: 'white',
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            lineColor: null,
                            enabled: true,
                            radius: 5
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true,
                    followPointer: true
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            loading: false,
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                title: {
                    text: 'Date/Time'
                },
                dataTimeLabelFormats:{
                    day:'%a',
                    week:'%a',
                },
                labels: {
                format: '{value:%a}'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                 pointIntervalUnit: 'hourly'
            }],
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            size: {
                height: 500
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to set the [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minRange) parameter, if it does not solve your issue, recreate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @SebastianBochan it does not solve my problem because minRange has a different utility all together. I really appreciate. :)  My requirement is that as you zoom into the chart it should show time in 24 hours. I am a bit confused how to achieve this. The configuration is what I have posted above.

Comment: @SebastianBochan The first problem was solved by using Tick Interval. So I am not able to see the repeated days since I made it to  24 * 3600 * 1000 on my xAxis. I will try further to show time in between them and let you know.